# Powertop reports "Bad" "Runtime PM for PCI Device"

Tags: linux, electrical-power, laptop

I've noticed that `powertop` utility reports "Bad" "Runtime PM for PCI Device" for several devices. Seems that `powertop` can fix the issue but it won't tell what exactly it does to fix it. What should I do to fix that "Runtime PM..." issue?

Answer (score 6):

Create a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-runtime-pm.rules` with the following content:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="pci", GOTO="power_runtime_rules_end"
ACTION!="add", GOTO="power_runtime_rules_end"

KERNEL=="????:??:??.?"
PROGRAM="/bin/sleep 0.1"

ATTR{power/control}=="*", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

LABEL="power_runtime_rules_end"
```

After a reboot runtime PM should be enabled for all devices that support it. It is also enables it for all hotplugged devices.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `power/control` attribute to `auto` for these devices. The easiest way to set it immediately for all PCI devices is:

```
echo auto | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control
```

Bash complains when using output redirection (`>`) to multiple files as `ambiguous redirect`.

If you want to set it permanently use approach described in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/358972/82513).

Answer (score 3):

Since the bios 2.11 update on the UX32VD this rule breaks usb device auto detection. I don't really know how, but since then to detect usb devices, the xhci_hcd module must be reloaded after a usb devce is connected to detect it.

Comment: Is there any fix known?

Comment: How to reload the xhci_hcd module?

Comment: @AndreasMueller check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AsusZenbookPrime#Enable_power_management for a possible work-around – disabling power management for the xHCI chip only.

Answer (score 2):

This [CrunchBang Linux forum thread](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/11954/laptop-power-saving-script-for-debian/) helped me to solve this.

You enable PM for each of your PCI devices this way :

```
echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/power/control
```

The forum thread shows a nice powersaving script btw.

Comment: Link is dead, archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20150207164556/http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=11954